# Can I close my account with all my posts removed?

Tags: support

Can I close my account and be sure that my posts expropriation be discontinued with my leaving?

Answer (score 6):

Please follow Jeff's directions here to delete your account:

[How can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/can-i-delete-my-account/7979#7979)

Basically, you need to edit your profile to say "Please delete me" and email team@serverfault.com telling them your user ID (which is 47886) and that you'd like your account to be deleted.

As far as your posts are concerned, I don't believe they will be automatically deleted. The community, however, will work through them to clean them up and remove them as necessary.

Comment: +1 - this advice will have your account deleted. If you wish to remove all posts, you can delete them yourself. A user is always able to delete his or her own comments or answers.

Comment: @MarkM, that is not entirely true.  You can not self delete answers once they have have been [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14932/allow-author-of-accepted-answer-to-delete-it-in-certain-circumstances).  Although this restriction will not be a problem for vgv8.

Comment: @Zordache - Haha! I did not realize that restriction. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: That's too funny, Zoredache!  +1, and Bravo!

Comment: 10k+ users can see everything, even "deleted" posts and all edits.